# Operator precedence of assignment and conditional operators

Tags: ruby, assignment-operator, operator-precedence

I'm reading a book called "The Ruby Programming Language" for Ruby 1.8 and 1.9. The book says that if-operator has a lower precedence than an assignment-operator. If this is true then I don't understand how this expressions works:

`x = 5 if false`

If assignment-operator has a higher precedence then it should be executed before an if-operator. So, 5 should be assigned to x before `if false` is executed.

Am I misunderstanding precedence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Higher precedence of assignment means that your expression evaluates to `(x = 5) if false`, and not to `x = (5 if false)`. Note, that later is a perfectly valid expression too.

Whether each particular clause is executed is determined by language rules. E.g., in a ternary operator `a ? b : c`, only `b` or `c` will be executed, but not both.

**edit**
About the difference.

In `x = (5 if false)`, assignment is processed first. But to complete it, we need left part of assignment, which is `nil`, because `5 if false` evaluates to `nil`. So, the expression is equivalent of `x = nil`.

In `(x = 5) if false`, conditional operator is processed first. According to its rules, we first have to evaluate condition (`false`). Since it's `false`, there's nothing more to do and result of evaluation is `nil`.

Hope that's clear.

Comment: +1 good examples. Think of precedence rules as a substitute for parentheses -- they tell you how things get grouped, and don't have anything to do with "before" or "after".

Comment: it was my understanding that "x = 5 if false" was in fact equivalent to "x = (5 if false)", but I think I got it wrong, what is the difference?

Comment: @tokland I've updated the answer, let me know if it helps. As *Nakilon* noted, you can rewrite `x = 5 if false` as `if (false) {x = 5}`.

Comment: thanks, @nikita. Doing some tests about this I discovered something I didn't know, which may be trivial but looks kind of weird: (a, b not defined) if false; a = 1; b = 2; end; p([a, b].inspect) gives "[nil, nil]"

Answer (score 0):

Because `<expr> if <condition>` is not a one expression. It is a special syntaxic sugar of Ruby. It works just like:

```
if <condition>
    <expr>
end
```

where, obviously, `<expr>` must be evaluated only after `<condition>` because `<condition>` can be `false`.

Comment: `<condition> ? <expr> : nil` would be more correct substitute. You can't really rewrite `doIt(3 if condition)` with normal `if` statement and that's not even very complicated example.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak, no, I can. `p(if some_boolean ; 0 ; end)` works well. P.S.: and I agree about `?:` – it has two levels of operations and illustrates `a if b` well.

Comment: Yeah, but that kinda breaks 'is not a one expression' part :) `if some_boolean ; 0 ; end` in your example is used as one expression.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak, `if some_boolean ; 0 ; end` is exactly what posted in answer.